# PHP Mail will not process ".com"

Tags: php, email

I know this is weird, but when a ".com" is added to the subject or body text to send PHP mail (like - xyz.com), the mail will not send. It's a problem with this hosting company (ipage) but i want to see if their is something i can do in the script itself, because it's a CMS of mines and i would like to keep generalized for everyone who uses it.

script is simple and as follows:

```
function confirmEmail($username, $email, $confirm_code) {

   $sitename = str_replace(".com", " .com", site_name);
   $subject  = "Your confirmation link here";
   $headers .= 'To: '.$username.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "From: ".$sitename." <".support_email.">". "\r\n";
   $message  = "Your Comfirmation link \n
   Click on this link to activate your account \n
   ".root."/confirm.php?confirm=$confirm_code";

   $message = wordwrap($message, 70);

   $sendmail = mail($username,$subject,$message,$headers);
   if ( $sendmail ) {
    return true;  
   } else {
    return false;
   }

  }
```

Now as you can see, i replace the **".com"** with **" .com"**(note the space at the beginning) for the $sitename variable, and that works but the problem is the "root" contains the full path to the givin site so the link is like "xyz.com/confirm.php?confirm=$confirm_code". I can't allow a space before the '.com' in the site path like 
**"xyz .com/etc..."** because the obviously the user can't click the link from within their email.

I know this is a weird problem and I have no clue on what's going on or what to even ask the hosting to change.

*note: site_name and root are defined previously in another page, and they work fine. Also no errors are being returned.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: NVM about my answer, understood the question wrong. There is no way of doing this while still retaining the links, you can do it the youtube way though: www.example DOT com

Comment: possibly a spam filter at play?

Comment: Consider a different route - if your hosting company's email is so busted, use a GMail account to send mail (through SMTP). Free and works very well.

Comment: spam filter eh? could you explain a little more? I take it this will be at the hands of the hosting company though?  And what do you mean by the youtube way? they wouldnt be able to click the link like xyzDOTcom will they??

Comment: just a guess, more urls = more likely spam and url in header also.

Comment: hey alex, i actually have that going on my new version that im still working on, though i have realized i may have to debut that update a little early. I could encourage users not to use .com's in their site titles, but I just can't, that'll suck SO BAD. and thanks Dagon, that gave me somthin to start with when i contact the hosting company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. Your workaround should not be necessary.

This is very likely a provider issue.

Don't know about your environment, but if you have not full control of your mailserver, try sending a mail with a link using telnet so you really see everything. Often spam filters etc are badly configured and don't return the correct codes.

If you don't have any luck with that I recommend switching to an external SMTP server that is well configured. You can perfectly use gmail for that if you dont send tons of mails.

Comment: Thank you, thats became more apparent in just the past few minutes of posting the question. I will sign up and log in so i can vote this answer. Thanks everyone

Comment: Actually can someone with higher rep vote this answer for me =)

Comment: OOoOO, click the lil green check mark, OoOoOOoOoOO =D. I clicked the arrow above the 0 -.-

Comment: file a suggestino that this should be outlined as long as you have not accepted at least one answer ;)